# Javascript keyword inputbox that redirects to url

Tags: javascript, url, keyword, inputbox

I have a site that uses javascript coding and such. I want to make an input box that when you type a certain keyword, it redirects you to a certain url.
Let's say I type "Cow" in the inputbox, and cow is a keyword. Then it will redirect me to a certain set url. But let's say I type "duck" in the box, and duck is ALSO a keyword, the it will send me to a different set url. Is this possible? and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var keywords = [
   {
       word: "cow",
       url: "my_cow_url"
   },
   {
       word: "duck",
       url: "my_duck_url"
   }
];
var txtbox = document.getElementById("myTextBoxId");
txtbox.addEventListener("keypress",function(){
    for (var i=0;i<keywords.length;i++){
       if (keywords[i].word === txtbox.value){
           window.location.href = keywords[i].url;
           return;
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to work, It says 'document' is undefined. Line 11.

Comment: Wow, which browser? try replacing that line with window.document.getElementById